# How to make a dynamic DataTextField in asp.net's HyperLinkColumn?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my Data Grid:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="dataGrid1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Valid" 
         DataTextField="Valid" 
          HeaderText="Enable / Disable"
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\examfilemanager\{0}" />
      </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I would like to have custom `DataTextField`, display `Enable` is the value is `true`, and `Disable` if the value is `false`, how can I add this logic in the HyperLinkColumn? Thanks.

Comment: i can not understand from where u get value true and false...where u decide it will b true or false

Comment: You want to change the header text or the row text? If it's header then the column values will be unique?

Comment: Sorry, I updated. I want to change the row text, not the header text.

Comment: its lot better u use a template field and put hyperlink inside templeate field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the text in ItemDataBound Event

```
protected void dataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Cells[0].Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        HyperLink hypLnk = (HyperLink)e.Item.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        if (hypLnk != null)
        {
            if (hypLnk.Text == "False")
                hypLnk.Text = "Enable";
            else
                hypLnk.Text = "Disable";
        }
    }
}
```

Data grid html

```
<asp:DataGrid id="dataGrid1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dataGrid1_ItemDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Valid" 
         DataTextField="Valid" 
          HeaderText="Enable / Disable"
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\examfilemanager\{0}" />
      </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hl1" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("uri.aspx?id={0}",Eval("id")) %>'
runat="server">Edit</asp:HyperLink>
```

Used this Below if you prefer HyperLink Column

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn
             HeaderText="Enable /Disable"
             DataNavigateUrlField="IntegerValue"
             DataNavigateUrlFormatString="examfilemanager.aspx?id={0}"
             DataTextField="Id"
             DataTextFormatString="{0:c}"
             Target="_blank"/>
     </Columns>
```

Comment: its grid view column not hyperlink

Comment: `enter code here` <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkColumn
                 HeaderText="Enable /Disable"
                 DataNavigateUrlField="IntegerValue"
                 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="examfilemanager.aspx?id={0}"
                 DataTextField="Id"
                 DataTextFormatString="{0:c}"
                 Target="_blank"/>
         </Columns>